# c4133 warning c code

Tags: c, string, pointers, strstr

I have a problem with warning c4133, it say that the problem is incopatible types from char* to int*, I try to cast the pointer ((char*)x) but with no luck, maybe someone knows whats the problem/

this is my program, the problem in the function.

```
void replaceSubstring(char *str, char *substr)//function that gets string and substring and      make the substring in string big letters
{
    int i;
    int  *x;

    x = (strstr(str, substr));//The problem line 
    while (strstr(str,substr) != NULL)
    {
        for (i=0;i<strlen(substr);i++)
        {
            *x = *x - 32;
            x++;//move to the next char
        }
        x = (strstr(str, substr));  //first apear of substr int str
    }
 }
```

Comment: Make `x` a `char*` because `strstr()` returns `char*`.Also in the `while` loop,I think you meant to use `while(x!=NULL)`

Comment: So why is `x` a pointer to `int`?

Comment: yes that what I ment ( while(x!=NULL)) but I try many thinks to figure out what the deal with the different level types, and I guess *x can be char but it doesnt works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototype of strstr is

```
 char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

Return value is  character pointer. So make the x as  a character pointer.

Comment: @TaniaGalan Error or anything ? Whats your input?

Comment: error but I solve it, the problem was that I wrote                       void replaceSubstring(char, char);                                      and I should write    void replaceSubstring(char*, char*);  thanks for help :)

Answer (score 7):

in your code, `x` is defined as `int *` but the return type of `strstr()` is `char *`.. Check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) here.

Worthy to mention, `cast`ing is usually considered a bad practice in `c`. With properly written code, most of the cases, `cast`ing can be avoided.  Most of the cases, `cast`ing *may* introduce lot of bugs. Double check the data types and stay away from `cast`ing.

Sidenote: Just a suggestion, maybe before directly subtracting `32` from `*x`, maybe you want to perform a range check on `*x` to be within `97-122` to ensure that is a lower-case letter.

Also, better to perform `strlen(substr)` outside the loop, store into a variable and use that value in looping. Will save you the overhead of redundant calls to `strlen()`.